# How to get a full info on exceptions in Python threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, exception, python-2.7

When exception occurs in a thread, instead of getting full exception info, that contains line number of exception, I get this:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function get_artist at 0x0000000002C2FEB8>
```

Can I manually write try, catch procedure which would print out the missing information about the exception?

I have tried:

```
except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

but, it still only prints the above message.

Comment: Can you try to create a reproducible example of the problem, perhaps by removing and simplifying code until the problem goes away? (It's possible the line that raises that exception isn't within the try except block)

Comment: Is your except-statement in the code running in the thread or is it in the main thread?

Comment: @Thorsten It is in the same tread, not in the parent thread

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried getting the exception using as? Something like this...

```
try:
    raise Exception('MONSTER!')
except Exception as ex:
    print 'The error is a %s' % ex

>>> The error is a MONSTER!
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps, now I know what the exception is. Is it also possible to get the line / line number?

Comment: @Ognjen well in my example you can print sys.exc_traceback.tb_lineno and that points to the right line. Will post the code in another answer...

Answer (score 0):

To get the line number:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        raise Exception('MONSTER!')
    except Exception as ex:
        print sys.exc_traceback.tb_lineno
```